# Query mysql somar valor dia aos dias anteriores

Tags: mysql

Tenho a seguinte query:

```
SELECT * FROM  vw_total_diario WHERE pessoa ='Daniel' GROUP BY data;
```

Ela retorna da seguinte forma:

```
2017-05-02 Daniel 6
2017-05-03 Daniel 2
2017-05-04 Daniel 8
2017-05-05 Daniel 1
2017-05-08 Daniel 10
2017-05-09 Daniel 2
2017-05-10 Daniel 8
2017-05-11 Daniel 6
2017-05-12 Daniel 5
2017-05-15 Daniel 4
```

Preciso que ela retorne assim (dia atual + dias anteriores):

```
2017-05-02 Daniel 6
2017-05-03 Daniel 8
2017-05-04 Daniel 16
2017-05-05 Daniel 17
2017-05-08 Daniel 27
2017-05-09 Daniel 29
2017-05-10 Daniel 37
2017-05-11 Daniel 43
2017-05-12 Daniel 48
2017-05-15 Daniel 52
```

Como poderia montar essa query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar uma `subquery` para somar a quantidade disponível nos dias anteriores:

```
SELECT vtd.*,
       (SELECT SUM(vtd2.total)
          FROM vw_total_diario vtd2
         WHERE vtd2.pessoa = vtd.pessoa
           AND vtd2.data <= vtd.data
         GROUP BY vtd2.pessoa) as total_quantidade
  FROM  vw_total_diario vtd
 WHERE pessoa = 'Daniel'
 GROUP BY data;
```

Comment: Ele fica retornando o seguinte: SQL execution error #1242. Response from the database:

 Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: @otaciojb falha minha, o `GROUP BY` estava errado

Comment: Pefeito,Muito Obrigado!